# How to check application is running under background process in task manager using command?

Tags: powershell, background-process, taskmanager

My application is running under background process in task manager without any window. I am using powershell script to check whether process is running or not and if not I'm restarting it. For that I'm using Get-Process method. But the issue is when app is not running still I'm seeing it under details tab in task manager. Which causes Get-Process giving output as process running. Is there any other way to check background process running or not like any command or relevant content?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if both Task Manager and `Get-Process` report the process as running then it probably _is_ running. What makes you think that it doesn't?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since, our app is running in background an dit is logging some user details in one file. But when app is running under details tab in task manager it is not logging anything in that file. So,I just wanted to check

Comment: Can you please help me in this issue. I'm stucked here. I can see my background application in details tab but not under processes and data sync is not happening at that time for app.